# Dynamically scrollable Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We have a Primefaces datatable which has a non-fixed number of columns. Basically, some header columns contains "+" buttons that unfold other columns.
Here are two pictures that show that behaviour:
[image: Folded column]
[image: Unfolded column]

These columns can have different widths (first one shows single digits, then doesn't need a lot of place while second one displays very long texts); each of them has a weight (we currently have 4 different weights).

Last point, the number of columns varies from 10 to 19. That's a lot of columns for a screen.

Thus, we would like to have the following behaviour:

- If the sum of every weight is less than a number, the datatable isn't scrollable.
- Else, the datatable is horizontally scrollable.

I have worked on that question for a few hours... And I haven't managed to find a solution.

---

Here is a MCV example:

My backing bean:

```
public class Bean implements Serializable{
    public void display3rdColumn() {
        m3rdColumnDisplayed = !m3rdColumnDisplayed;
    }

    private boolean m3rdColumnDisplayed = false;
    public boolean isM3rdColumnDisplayed() {
        return m3rdColumnDisplayed;
    }
    public void setM3rdColumnDisplayed(boolean m3rdColumnDisplayed) {
        this.m3rdColumnDisplayed = m3rdColumnDisplayed;
    }

    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

JSF code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.elements}"
             style="text-align:center;">

    <p:column headerText="1st column">
        <p:outputLabel value="1"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel escape="false">
                2nd column
                <br/>
                <p:commandButton
                        icon="fa fa-plus"
                        actionListener="#{bean.display3rdColumn}"
                        update="@form"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputLabel value="Very very long description with a lot of text - don't I deserve a lot of place?"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="3rd column" rendered="#{bean.m3rdColumnDisplayed}">
        <p:outputLabel value="Not that long description"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

---

Does an "easy" solution exist? Or is this a really tough question?

Comment: Add `scrollable=#{bean.yourLogicToDetermineIfScrollable()}` and `scrollWidth="100%"` to the datatable, and in the bean calculate your column weights based on what is visible and return true if scrollable, else return false.

Comment: @AshishMathew Thanks for your reply! Two issues still remain. Firstly, I always have to have vertical scrolling. It doesn't fit with your solution. I surely can add a paginator to remove this need. The real problem is when I set a scrollWidth > 72: when I unfold columns, the datatable is resized but doesn't become scrollable. But when I set a scrollwidth <= 72, the datatable effectively becomes horizontally scrollable... Is it a known bug or a mistake of mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve my issue. I have set "tableStyle" to "table-layout: auto;", "resizableColumns" to "true" and a paginator. I have removed  the fixed width for each column.

The point is that my columns can be resized by the user and I can't give them programmatically a width because it is automatically set. Nevertheless, it is the nearest solution I have found.